# ng-file-drop does not work with 7zip

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

When I drag a file from within 7zip into the drag and drop area, the filename appears as if it was a successful upload but it fails to upload on submit. I would like to prevent having the filename appear if it's from 7zip or similar. When I use the demo on https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/ it works as I expect it to. I'm running version 3.2.5

How can I prevent the filename from appearing if it's coming from 7zip?

```
<div data-ng-file-drop class="document-drop-area" data-ng-model="additionalDocumentFiles" data-ng-multiple="true" drag-over-class="{accept:'document-drop-accept', reject:'document-drop-reject', delay:100}">
                Drag/Drop Files Here
            </div>
```

Comment: this 7zip is a file format?

Comment: No, it's when I'm dragging a file within the 7zip explorer. The web version doesn't allow me to do it, but in my application it recognizes the file name but can't upload it. I would rather the application not recognize anything